# CSS Styling a 'div' element nested deep inside other elements

Tags: html, css, nested

This is how the code looks:

[image]

And I want to a border for the highlighted element, i.e. `<div class="Comment">...</div>`, how do I style it using CSS?

***NOTE:*** Notice the class named 'Comment'? It is used in both the highlighted element and it's parent element. So, that's probably why this one's a bit tricky?

I tried the CSS codes below, and some others, and none worked.

```
.DataList .Item .comment, .DataList .Comment .comment,
.DataList .FirstComment .comment, .DataList .Mine .comment {
    border:1px solid #666;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:3px;
        -moz-border-radius:3px;
        -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}

.DataList .Item div.comment, .DataList .Comment div.comment,
.DataList .FirstComment div.comment, .DataList .Mine div.comment {
    border:1px solid #666;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:3px;
        -moz-border-radius:3px;
        -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Hope someone can help me solve this small riddle. Thanks.

Comment: @j08691 I was pretty stupid. I was always testing `.comment` and `div.comment` not noticing the case. I should have instead typed `.Comment` or `div.Comment.` LOL!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, try NOT styling with extreme specificity (adding parent/element selectors). this way, you can just use `.Comment` - **note that they ARE case sensitive.**

if styles are overridden or you have selectors of the same name but different "context" (like you have a list item with `.Comment` and it's child with div with `.Comment`), that's when you use higher specificity (adding the parent/element in the selector) like `div.Comment`, `.Item .Comment`

Comment: Oh, damn! How could I miss that?! I didn't notice that I was using the wrong case. Thanks a lot for correcting me. :)